# Authentication fails when scene changes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I setup my firebase authentication and it works very well. However, when I load a different scene and after turn back to welcome scene, authentication fails. What should I do for re-auth or keep signed in while scenes changing?

My Code for welcome scene for auth:

```
public void Start()
    {
        InitializeFirebase();
        InitializePlayGamesPlatform();
        SignInPlayGames();        
    }

public void InitializeFirebase()
    {
        Debug.Log("UserManager: Setting up Firebase Auth");
        auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        auth.StateChanged += AuthStateChanged;
        auth.IdTokenChanged += IdTokenChanged;
        // Specify valid options to construct a secondary authentication object.
        if (otherAuthOptions != null &&
            !(String.IsNullOrEmpty(otherAuthOptions.ApiKey) ||
              String.IsNullOrEmpty(otherAuthOptions.AppId) ||
              String.IsNullOrEmpty(otherAuthOptions.ProjectId)))
        {
            try
            {
                otherAuth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.GetAuth(Firebase.FirebaseApp.Create(
                  otherAuthOptions, "Secondary"));
                otherAuth.StateChanged += AuthStateChanged;
                otherAuth.IdTokenChanged += IdTokenChanged;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Debug.Log("UserManager: ERROR: Failed to initialize secondary authentication object.");
            }
        }
        AuthStateChanged(this, null);        
    }

public void InitializePlayGamesPlatform()
    {
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
            .RequestServerAuthCode(false)
            .Build();

        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

        auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    }

public void SignInPlayGames()
{
    connecting = true;
    ServerConnectionStatus.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Connecting to PlayGames";
    ServerConnectionStatus.GetComponent<Text>().color = Color.black;

    Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
        if (!success)
        {
            Debug.LogError("UserManager: Failed to Sign in into PlayGames Service");
            ServerConnectionStatus.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cannot Connect to PlayGames";
            ServerConnectionStatus.GetComponent<Text>().color = Color.red;
            connecting = false;
            return;
        }

        AuthCode = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetServerAuthCode();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AuthCode))
        {
            Debug.LogError("UserManager: Signed in into PlayGames Service, Failed to get Server Auth Code");
            ServerConnectionStatus.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cannot Connect to PlayGames";
            ServerConnectionStatus.GetComponent<Text>().color = Color.red;
            connecting = false;
            return;
        }

        Debug.LogFormat("UserManager: Server Auth Code = {0}", AuthCode);

        Credential credential = PlayGamesAuthProvider.GetCredential(AuthCode);
        auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.LogError("UserManager: SignInWithCredentialAsync was canceled.");
                ServerConnectionStatus.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cannot Sign in to PlayGames";
                ServerConnectionStatus.GetComponent<Text>().color = Color.red;
                task.Exception.ToString();
                connecting = false;
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("UserManager: SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                ServerConnectionStatus.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Cannot Sign in to PlayGames";
                ServerConnectionStatus.GetComponent<Text>().color = Color.red;
                connecting = false;
                return;
            }

            user = task.Result;
            Debug.LogFormat("UserManager: User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
                user.DisplayName, user.UserId);
            ServerConnectionStatus.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Connected to PlayGames";
            ServerConnectionStatus.GetComponent<Text>().color = Color.green;
            connected = true;
            connecting = false;
            nick = auth.CurrentUser.DisplayName;
            SetPlayerName(nick);
        });
    });
}

public void SetPlayerName(string value)
{
    PhotonNetwork.NickName = value;
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("PlayerName", value);
}

void AuthStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth senderAuth = sender as Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth;
        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser user = null;
        if (senderAuth != null) userByAuth.TryGetValue(senderAuth.App.Name, out user);
        if (senderAuth == auth && senderAuth.CurrentUser != user)
        {
            bool signedIn = user != senderAuth.CurrentUser && senderAuth.CurrentUser != null;
            if (!signedIn && user != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("UserManager: Signed out " + user.UserId);
            }
            user = senderAuth.CurrentUser;
            userByAuth[senderAuth.App.Name] = user;
            if (signedIn)
            {
                Debug.Log("UserManager: Signed in " + user.UserId);
                displayName = user.DisplayName ?? "";
                DisplayDetailedUserInfo(user, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Result Error:

> 04-01 01:37:41.330: E/Unity(6065): UserManager: SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
>
> ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
>
> ---> Firebase.FirebaseException: The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Error getting access token from playgames.google.com, OAuth2 redirect uri is: http://localhost, response: OAuth2TokenResponse{params: error=invalid_grant&error_description=Bad%20Request, httpMetadata: HttpMetadata{status=400, cachePolicy=NO_CACHE, cacheDuration=null, cacheImmutable=false, staleWhileRevalidate=null, filename=null, lastModified=null, headers=HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first time it works as expected it sounds like [`DontDestroyOnLoad`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) is what you're looking for:

Doesn't destroy that object when switching scenes -> therefore doesn't run the `Start` method again. However, you also would need to combine it with a `singleton` pattern to make sure it isn't added/run a second time when coming back to that first scene:

```
public class AuthComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static AuthComponent singleton;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // Check if already another AuthComponent running
        if(singleton)
        {
            Debug.Log("Already another AuthComponent running");
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }

        // Otherwise store a global reference of this AuthComponent
        singleton = this;

        // and make it DontDestroyOnLoad
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Should I create another script with the code above and add it to my UserManager gameobject where it contains all auth staff inside? Sorry, maybe a silly question but I am not familiar with this :/

Comment: For example yes. I didn't know how your class is called. You can as well simply add it directly in `UserManager`.

Comment: I did not succeed to implement singleton yet but after my detail search, singleton is the way to do it. I have now different problems thanks to singleton :) I will try to fix them, thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

I tried a lot but I dont get the desired behavior (about re-auth / application dont quit)

Even if I changing scenes, credentials remain.

If you want to change account,

re-start application and than logout(facebook or google) in welcome scene

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is; when I open welcome scene first time and ask for user.DisplayName; it works perfectly. When I open another scene and after turn back to welcome scene, the user.Displayname returns null. When I try to relaunch firebase functions, it does not sign in and gives the above error. Did you try sonething similar to my example?

Comment: Btw, I do not want to change the account, just want the user to keep signed in.

Comment: I dont use user.DisplayName. Did you make it a singleton this class?
If you need displayname, save in this class or Playerprefs

Comment: I did not try singleton and not much familiar with it. However, if the logic is to run it once, I already tried it by removing functions from start and execute them manually. Is there any other reason for singleton?

Comment: I think, if you want to have authentication information anywhere or only one exists class, you should make singleton class. and this class should not be destroyed. My firebaseManager class is using anywhere.

Comment: During changeing scene your class might have been destroyed. and re-created

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it. Could you please show me a small sample how can I do it?

Comment: DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject); add this to your init script on start

Comment: singleton
https://codeburst.io/singleton-design-pattern-implementation-in-c-62a8daf3d115

DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
this code add in init or awake